# Dot formatting issue with cucumber

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, cucumber

In the result for our cucumber tests, we are getting ugly line breaks. This occurs after using execute_script to autocomplete a field, but only when we are querying on the term '5x1'. I don't think this is a problem with the capybara parser, since '5x1' will not demonstrate this behavior if included in a longer string. It could be the autocomplete function, but the same command in the actual JavaScript console doesn't show this behavior either. I've attached a picture showing the break that shows up when running the whole suite as well as just in pry.

The exact code that breaks it is page.execute_script("$(elem).autocomplete('search', '5x1')

[image: broken line on 5x1]

[image: broken lines]

Comment: Can you share some code that reproduces the problem?